# C# System.Threading.Thread.Sleep is slow

Tags: c#, sleep

I'am using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);` but i think is to slow, I'dont know why, but it is.

Look at my code:

```
    clickButton();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AFTER_CLICK_PAGE);
```

I want first `clickButton();` and after I need `sleep` program. But if i run code, program **first sleep and after sleep call method** `clickButton();` ?Why? I don't understand this...

Program is only in one thread.

EDIT code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clickButton();
    timer1.Stop();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AFTER_CLICK_PAGE);
    timer1.Start();
}
private void clickButton()
{   
                       webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_ad_button").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code? Maybe it is a async method?

Comment: What means "Sleep is too slow"? Sleep blocks the current thread for x milliseconds! Look at the reply of Steve...it is the corrected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the behaviour you are expecting is:

1. Click a button
2. Update a bunch of stuff (visibly)
3. Sleep

But what happens is the visible update doesn't happen until after the sleep...

You need to force the change to the UI before you sleep, as you are preventing it. You can normally do this by adding...

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Before the sleep.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but if I use `Application.DoEvents();` `webBrowser1` is on page on which to click on the button - but if I delete `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AFTER_CLICK_PAGE);` it's work. But no with sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Sleep` does all manner of weird stuff. It might be that the invokation of the click is stored on some queue and that queue is affected by Sleep. I don't know exactly but I know that `Sleep` should be avoided at all costs.

I suggest you use two timers instead of one. One for clicking, one for waiting, that enables the first timer again. If you do this, you let your application do its stuff while you are waiting. With `Thread.Sleep` it stops whatever it is doing until the time is up.

Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrClick = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrWait = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tmrClick.Interval = 2000;
        tmrClick.Enabled = true;
        tmrClick.Tick += tmrClick_Tick;

        tmrWait.Interval = 2000; //SLEEP_AFTER_CLICK_PAGE
        tmrWait.Enabled = false;
        tmrWait.Tick += tmrWait_Tick;
    }
    private void tmrClick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "CLICK";
        tmrClick.Stop();
        tmrWait.Start();
    }

    private void tmrWait_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "WAIT DONE";
        tmrWait.Stop();
        tmrClick.Start();
    }
}
```